# Other daemon process like mediaserverd cause OOM?

Tags: ios, out-of-memory

As we know mediaserverd daemon process can cause app foreground OOM and get killed, is there way to get how many memory used by these daemon process or get other daemon process will cause app foreground OOM?

Comment: What do you mean? you want to know how much memory does mediaserverd use? or how much memory is used by your app?

Comment: My app get OOM killed at a low memery usage (about 300~600MB)，I suspect that there exist other process like mediaserverd use a lot of memory and cause my app foreground oom. So I want to know how much memory used that cause the oom, except my app.

Comment: I think you might be able to do this using the `Instruments.app` that comes with xcode.

Comment: Yeah, instrument is useful to analyze OOM that can be reproduced, and I get a lot of OOM case that have no idea about how to reproduce. I want to get some advice from development experience